# Issue while changing the profile picture after deploying the code in server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using **twitter bootstrap**. I'm **changing the profile picture**. I'm just saving the picture in a folder and retrieving it again. It works fine in local system but **it is not working after deploying the code in the server**. But picture is getting saved in the folder and not getting Changed in .aspx page. When i log out and log in again,its getting refreshed.

Here is my code :

```
  <img runat="server" id="ImgPic" />  
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" runat="server"/>         
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="lnkChangePic" runat="server" onclick="ChangePicture();">Change</a>

  <asp:Button ID="btnChangeUserPic" runat="server" OnClick="btnChangeUserPic_Click"
        class="hidden" />   


function ChangePicture(){
  $('#btnChangeUserPic').click();
}

 protected void btnChangeUserPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Images/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }
            string file = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower();
            HttpPostedFile hpfFile = fileUpload.PostedFile;
            if (file != "")
            {
                string fileExtn = Path.GetExtension(hpfFile.FileName).ToLower();

                if (fileExtn == ".jpg")
                {                       
                    string filename = filePath +System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpfFile.FileName);
                    if (File.Exists(filename))
                    {
                        File.Delete(filename);
                    }
                    hpfFile.SaveAs(filename); 
                    ImgPic.src=    filename;                 
                }                   
            }            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
        } 
   }
```

**The Picture should get updated in master page also.**

Thank you all in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by 'getting refreshed' but.. the filepath on your server is not going to be the same as on you local machine. Use Server.MapPath instead of a simple string;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

Also check you permissions to the folder and show us the code in whatever UI page that actually displays the picture, how is that getting set?

Comment: im using `Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Images/")` only. Picture is not updated in .aspx page in runtime

Comment: i have given both read and write permission to that **Images** folder

Answer (score 0):

My guess (there's not enough info) is that ImgPic.src is holding the URL for the img tag.  This would explain why it works locally but not on the server, because you've set

```
ImgPic.src=    filename;
```

it should be set to the URL, not the mapped path.

If it's not that please post info on where the img is getting it's src set.